# How to display a UITextView programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am trying to display a basic `UITextView` programmatically. The problem is, if I want to display a `UILabel` with the same constraints and settings, it's all fine, I can have it displayed. However, if I change it to a `UITextView`, it just disappears. I created an empty project, just to check it, but still, no avail, just does not display.
Here's my code that works fine for a `UILabel`:

```swift
view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

explanationView = UILabel()
explanationView.layer.zPosition = 1
explanationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
explanationView.numberOfLines = 10
view.addSubview(explanationView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    explanationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor),
    explanationView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
    explanationView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
    explanationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
])
```

I am using `layer.zPosition` to display it over a `UIImageView`. I also add `.isScrollEnabled` for the text view. I also tried creating the `UITextView` via a computed property, but did not have any luck either.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Below is the code that I use for the text view.

```swift
explanationView = UITextView()
explanationView.layer.zPosition = 1
explanationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
explanationView.isScrollEnabled = true
view.addSubview(explanationView)
```

Comment: Please share your textview creation code as well.

Comment: Updated with the `UITextView` code.

Comment: Does it show if you add a frame to it?

Comment: It does on a new project, not this one, but I need to comment out the constraints to get it working. I used `.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)`.